# Taking square roots in equations

Tags: roots

When are we allowed to take square roots in an equation?

For example, $x^2 = (x+2)^2$

Are we allowed to take square roots to solve it?

Comment: You can, if you take care with the signs.  $a^2=b^2\iff a=\pm b$.

Comment: but if we do take roots in this example, we get:

either -x=x+2

or x=x+2

meaning x=-1

or 0=2!

Comment: Ok, so the case $x=x+2$ does not correspond to a possible value of $x$.  That's ok.  The other case works.

Comment: Taking square roots is something to be done with care, as others have noted, to make sure that all possibilities have been identified. Care is also needed when squaring - because this can introduce solutions which were not solutions of the original equation. The basic rule is check the answer in the original equation.

Answer (score 2):

You can take roots, just be aware of the fact that $\sqrt{a^2} = |a|$. So solving $x^2 = (x+2)^2$ is equivalent to solving $|x| = |x+2|$.

**UPDATE**

Next step is to remember that

- if $x\le-2$ then the equation becomes $-x = -(x+2)$, which simplifies to $0=-2$ and so has no solutions;
- if $-2<x<0$ then we get $-x=x+2$, which implies $x=-1$
- if $x\ge 0$ then we get $x=x+2$, which again has no solutions.

So there is only one solution to the equation at $x=-1$.

Comment: so how would you solve  |x|=|x+2|?

Comment: @dugdugdug We reduce it to the two possible cases $-x=x+2$ or $x=x+2.$ It's the same thing we'd get by factoring $$(x+2)^2-x^2=0$$ as a difference of squares to get $$[(x+2)+x][(x+2)-x]=0,$$ whence $(x+2)+x=0$ or $(x+2)-x=0,$ or more simply, $2x+2=0$ or $2=0.$ Clearly, then, $2x+2=0,$ which is easy to solve.

Comment: so it's the equivalent of taking roots but discarding the "wrong" part of the solution, ie discard 2x+2=0 and go with (x+2)+x=0?

Comment: @dugdugdug please see the update

Answer (score 1):

Let's work through equivalences:$$\begin{align}x^2=(x+2)^2&\iff x=x+2\lor -x=x+2\\&\iff-x=x+2\\&\iff x=-1.\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks but what does the V sign mean?

Comment: @dugdugug $\lor$ (`\lor`) means [inclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction).

Answer (score 0):

If |a|= |b| then either a= b or a= -b.  So if |x|= |x+ 2| either x= x+ 2 or x= -(x+ 2)= -x- 2.  If x= x+ 2 then, subtracting x from both sides, 0- 2 which, of course, is not true.  x is not equal to x+ 2.    If x= -x- 2, adding x to  both sides, 2x= -2 so x= -1. You can (and should) check back in the original problem:  if x= -1, x^2= (-1)^2= 1 while (x+ 2)^2= (-1+ 2)^2= 1^2= 1.  Yes, they are equal!

Comment: The reason for posing this question is as a student, you follow what teachers say, ie whatever you do to one side of an equation, you do to the other.

But by taking roots, you end up with 0=2, which clearly doesn't make sense.

So if the student asks: "when can you take roots?", would the correct answer be, "always but be careful"?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved instead as $$(x+2)^2-x^2=0=(x+2+x)(x+2-x)=4(x+1)$$

Using the difference of two squares in this way saves the taking of square roots, and can be less error-prone as well as making it clear what is going on.

The "missing solution" from the quadratic is identified by setting $x=\frac 1y$ so that $$\frac {1}{y^2}=\left(\frac 1y+2\right)^2$$ or $$1=\left(1+2y\right)^2$$ which has the solution $y=0$ and indicates a "missing solution at infinity". $y=-1$ corresponds to the original solution for $x$.

Comment: so would the method for solving x^2=(x+2)^2 be the same as solving:

x^100=(x+2)^100

Comment: @dugdugdug - not really, or perhaps yes. To use the same method you need to know that $y^{100}-x^{100}$ is the product of $100$ linear factors of the form $(y-\alpha x)$ where $\alpha$ is a $100^{th}$ root of unity. Each root of unity gives a linear factor, and each linear factor potentially gives a solution. In the concrete case you give,  still have the missing solution at infinity (where the factorisation contains a constant factor). The solution can always be done by taking $100^{th}$ roots directly, provided all the roots are considered.